# Closing an outermost stream object in Java

Tags: java, stream, fileinputstream

When I write something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt")));
br.close();
```

closing the outermost object, in this case **br**, will automatically close all the chained objects too.

But what if there's still a reference to a chained object?

Something like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
br.close();
```

In this case, I don't want **fis** to be released, because I need to use it in the other stream soon.

So is it okay to call **br**'s **close()** here, and still can use **fis**?

Comment: What other stream would you have to use it in? Why? That's your problem right there.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "need to use it in the other stream", you know streams do not have to support going back?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, you maybe right. I don't remember the exact situation but well, it wouldn't had to be done that way as you said. But I want to know what will happen in this case, because I'm still learning Java and want to know how it works.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't mean to be rude, but I often see people here just saying "why are you gong to do that?" and not answering anything.. I think asking something curious isn't that bad, if it can help someone understand something well. This place isn't for the practical coders only. I DON'T KNOW BUT DON'T DO THAT BECAUSE THAT'S BAD isn't really the answer..

Comment: People often ask "why" because they do not want to directly tell OP that they must not do something for reason X. Answer here is: you can use fis, you probably cant do much with it, the variable will still be valid but you will not be able to read from the stream.

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry if it sounded a bit rude, I didn't mean it. You're right, I added my reason here and it's not reasonable so people can say what you said. I now understand. Thanks for the answer too, but it's not clear to me. It seems like it's already released by close() because you said I won't be able to read from the stream..

Comment: No offence taken, there was nothing rude, dont worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it okay to call br's close() here, and still can use fis?

**No!**

Once `br` has wrapped `fis`, `fis` should not be used for any other purpose because `br` has made the assumption that `fis` is for it and it alone to do with it what it wishes. It could, for example, pre-buffer some or even all of the `fis` during construction among many other things.

Using `fis` for anything other than what `br` uses it for will not only give unpredictable results but it will most likely interfere with `br`'s functionality significantly.

Even if all you do is close `br` immediately after creating it it is quite reasonable for `fis` to then be at least part-consumed if not completely consumed - it is also supposed to be closed.